# Difference between relaxing and setting weight in graph theory

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Can I say relaxing an edge is same as setting its weight to 0 in graph theory?

I know that setting the negative weights can lead to shortest paths with infinite edges, but is it the same case with setting the weight to 0